# Laravel 4 Chumper\Datatable package, All records have same ID

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I am working with Chumper's Datatable package for laravel 4 (https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable) and almost everything works fine. Here is my function inside controller class that returns json for datatable.

```
public function datatable() {
    $sortingColumns = array( "title", null, null, "link", "modules.title", "priority", "status" );
    $orderByColumn =  $sortingColumns[ $_POST["iSortCol_0"] ];

    $submodulesQuery = Submodule::select(DB::raw("submodules.*, modules.id, modules.title as module"))
                            ->join("modules", "submodules.module_id", "=", "modules.id");

    return Datatable::query($submodulesQuery)
                ->showColumns(array("title","description", "icon", "link", "module", "priority", "status"))
                ->searchColumns(array("submodules.title", "modules.title"))
                ->orderColumns( $orderByColumn )
                ->addColumn("title", function($submodule) {
                    $route = route("administration.submodules.show", $submodule->id);
                    return "<a href='$route'>$submodule->title</a>";
                })
                ->addColumn("icon", function($submodule) {
                    if( $submodule->icon === NULL || strlen($submodule->icon) === 0 )
                        return "NULL";
                    return "<i class='{$submodule->icon}'></i>";
                })
                ->addColumn("actions", function($submodule) {
                    $id = $submodule->id;
                    return 
                        "<div>
                            <a href='/administration/submodules/{$id}/edit'><button title='Edit submodule' type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'><i class='icon-pencil'></i></button></a>
                            <button title='Delete submodule' type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' onclick='deleteSubmodule({$id}); return false;'><i class='icon-trash'></i></button>
                        </div>";
                })->make();
}
```

For the column named 'actions' which I add at the very end I need to get submodule's ID inorder to provide correct route for edit and delete actions. However at that point every single submodule that is past as argument has same ID = 1. In database things are different. Those IDs are different since they are primary keys. What is wrong here? Why do I get same ID for every single submodule object passed as argument to callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a problem it was in my query. I should put alias on that modules.id column since it overrides submodules.id and I only have one module at this moment.